# Performing a Wald-test on Hazard-ratio without PH assumption

Tags: survival, wald-test

I have data on the duration of treatments. There is a disturbance at t=0 (treatment tariffs radically increase), which leads to an sudden increase in the number of treatments closed at that point.

I am trying to implement the methodology of a recently published [paper](http://file:///C:/Users/KGR310/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Content.Outlook/1ZA6C0A7/aer.20170092.pdf) with a similar setup. In this paper, the authors consider the situation in terms of a survival analysis and they calculate the hazard rate directly before (t=-1) of the disturbance, and directly following the disturbance (t=1). They then divide one hazard rate by the other to obtain a hazard-ratio. (See p.3250) They use a Wald-test to show that this ratio is significantly different from 1. (They present the p-values of this wald-test).

My problem is calculating this Wald-test.

In order, to calculate the Wald-test, I need the standard error of the hazard ratio. I've looked this up and all I could find was the **Mantel Haenszel approach** or **logrank-appraoch**, both of which assume proportionality in hazard-rates, which my model will not pass.

My question is how would you go about performing this Wald-test?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to follow the link to the paper you cite so I can't comment on that approach.

Your outcome appears to be a count ("Frequency").  I suggest a Poisson regression of Frequency on Time with a discontinuity just before 0.  Something like (in R):

glm(yy ~ xx + I(xx >= 0), family = "poisson")

or perhaps

glm(yy ~ xx * I(xx >= 0), family = "poisson")

if you want the 'slope' to be different before and after the discontinuity.

Then most software will provide the Wald test for each coefficient in your model.

## make up some data similar to yours

set.seed(20191125)

xx <- seq(-14,54)

yy <- c(1750, 1500, 1300, 1100, 900,
                750, 650, 550, 500, 400,
                350, 330, 260, 250, 370,
                350, 300, 260, 240, 200,
                175, 150, 125, 100, 75,
                60, 50, 50, 50, 55,
                60, 50, 40, 30, 20,
                round(runif(10) * 10),
                round(runif(24) * 6))

plot(xx, yy, type="l")

## fit models

mod1 <- glm(yy ~ xx + I(xx >= 0), family = "poisson")

summary(mod1)

points(xx, predict(mod1, type="response"), col=2)

mod2 <- glm(yy ~ xx * I(xx >= 0), family = "poisson")

summary(mod2)

points(xx, predict(mod2, type="response"), col=3)

Comment: This is the direction I am heading as well. Here is a follow-up question on the same problem: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051206/adding-constraints-to-glm-regression-that-sum-to-zero)  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Realized that the main issue is estimating the standard error for a ratio. After some reading I also realized that the easiest way to accomplish this is bootstrapping it.